# Getting all posts from a user

Tags: laravel

I'm really new to Laravel and ran it some problems. I have a /user/USERNAME view, which obviously, shows the users profile. But now I want to get ALL posts the user posted to be shown on his profile.

My web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::any('/user/{username}', [
        'as'   => 'user',
        'uses' => 'UserController@view_user' 
    ]);
});
```

My User model

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

My Post model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My UserController

```
public function view_user($username = null) {
        $user = null;

        $user = User::where('name', $username)->firstOrFail();
        $posts = Post::where('creator', $username)->get();

        return view('/user', [
            'user' => $user,
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }

    public function index() {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('user', compact('posts'));
    }
```

When I'm trying to get the posts with for example {{ $posts->title }} it gives me: Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.

How am I supposed to do this the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$posts` returns a collection, so in order to retrieve the title of a post you need to loop through the single items of the collection. Then you can use `$post->title`.